# jsonlite - how do I control output of long numbers?

Tags: r, jsonlite

I can not figure out how to control the output from jsonlite::toJSON() so that high precision numbers are represented as is.

For example:

```
l <- list(x = 1.001000000000987466525, y = 0.0000022624065747878902023)
jsonlite::toJSON(l, pretty = TRUE, digits = NA, auto_unbox = TRUE)

{
  "x": 1.00100000000099,
  "y": 2.26240657478789e-06
}
```

I would like the output of toJSON to preserve the exact value in l as follows:

```
{
  "x": 1.001000000000987466525,
  "y": 0.0000022624065747878902023
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: It's impossible, in `l` they already striped to 15 significant digits. You can only store them as a string and use long arithmetic.